# VIM - working with FuzzyFinder

Tags: vim, file-management, plugins

I just started using VIM, and really missing the quick-open file feature most descent text-editors have. I added FuzzyFinder to my plugins, but can't figure out how to best make it do just that - search recursively and open a file in the current dir I'm working in (including subdirs!) by specifying part of the file name. I Right now it makes me walk through all the subdirs until I find what I need. So I have to name each part of the full path until I find what I want. I'm using the :FufFile option. For example (rails app root folder):

```
app

app > views

app > views > main

app > views > main > index.erb (found!)
```

In each case I have to enter at least 1-2 letters of the dir/file for the level I'm in, when all I want to do is type a couple of letters and be shown all the files that match that pattern. Am I doing it wrong, or is there some kind of customization needed? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent versions of Vim, you can specify a recursive search for a file by prefixing the file name with `**/`.  Following your example, you could type

```
:e **/in
```

followed by a tab to see a list of all the files in the current directory and below beginning with "in" and with "in" expanded to the longest common prefix.  See also

```
:help wildcard
:help cmdline-completion
```

The version of Vim about to be released, 7.3, will add file name expansion to the recursive searching capability of the `find` command.  Then, adding `**` to your `'path'` option will give you the behavior you want:  type `:find`, the first few letters of the file name and a tab to have the name expanded to the matching names in the current directory and below.